# How to deactivate the functionality of UITapGestureRecognizer for my checkboxes?

Tags: ios, checkbox, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a UIView with an UITapGestureRecognizer and on top I use textFields and checkboxes. I want to use this gestureRecongizer to remove the keyboard by clicking anywhere else.

But know my checkboxes call the selector of the recongizer? 
How can I avoid this behavior?I already tried the exclusiveTouch property but it didn't work.

Anyone who can recommend me a good workflow for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Register as your recognizer delegate `tapRecognizer.delegate = self;` (declare that you are UIGestureRecognizerDelegate)

2- Implement **shouldReceiveTouch**

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

}
```

3- Check the touch.view to decide if the gesture should take care of that touch.  In you case, return NO if its the checkbox view.

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[yourCheckboxClass class]]) {
    return NO; // ignore the touch
    }
    return YES;
    }
```

*(You dont have to use isKindOfClass, You can use any other way to determine if its your checkbox)*

Comment: This solution works really nice and easy - Thank you :)

btw. my condition is:
if (touch.view == self.button) ..

Answer (score 0):

You're checkboxes are probably a custom bit of code? A button or another type of UIView, as long as they are a subview of the UIView, and do not have their own method of handling a tap (like a UITextField for example) they will end up calling their superviews recognizer.

So you could get around this by giving each checkbox it's own recognizer, and let them handle whatever happens then, or a recognizer for all the checkboxes. This could then handle your tap to check or uncheck the checkbox.

For example something along the lines of this.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap):];

    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [checkbox addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
}

- (void) handleSingeTap: (id) sender
{
  //check/uncheck the apropriate chexbox
}
```

Comment: Yes, they are custom in code and yes it works, thank you. 

But I didn't mentioned that I have 2 checkboxes and a button which are infected by this recognizer. It isn't a really beautiful solution if I add to each button/checkbox an own additional gestureRecognizer, isn't it?

Is there a better way?

Comment: You could set the tags of the checkboxes and button, and then within the single handler function check which object it is by checking the tag and determine your action from there on out.

Answer (score 0):

I found a third even more easy way !

I used the gestures property "cancelsTouchesinview" and set it to "NO"

```
gesture.cancelsTouchesinview = NO;
```